# State ID Count after SDE Compression

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-10.5, compression

I have a Enterprise Geodatabase (SDE) in SQL Server 2016. 
I have a nightly python script to preform some maintenance including the compress function (among other things).

I am noticing that the state counts after the compress are not going lower than 8. The before state count is higher but no matter what the count never reaches 1 (sometimes it does go to 7).

Why is the count staying at this number after the compress? does this indicate something is wrong, or a possible conflict/issue in the near future?

[image]

Comment: do you have any version that exists at this time? (it could be some other nightly scripts that use a version)

Comment: yah I do not delete the versions after reco/post compress they are still present (2+ default)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a compress is done while some versions still exist, the state count will never reach 1, as each version has its own state(s).

If you do a reconcile/post on each version before doing the compres, the state count should be `number of versions + 1`

To reach 1, delete all versions before doing the compress.

This [doc](http://%20To%20reach%201,%20delete%20all%20versions%20before%20doing%20the%20compress.) has some good graphics to depict the state/session relation (see the `compress` section)